# Can someone help with big O notation?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

```
void printScientificNotation(double value, int powerOfTen)
{
if (value >= 1.0  &&  value < 10.0)
{
    System.out.println(value + " x 10^" + powerOfTen);
}
else if (value < 1.0)
{
    printScientificNotation(value * 10, powerOfTen - 1);
}
else     // value >= 10.0
{
    printScientificNotation(value / 10, powerOfTen + 1);
}
```

}

assuming that imputs will not lead to infinite loops

I understand how the method goes but I cannot figure out a way to represent the method. 
For example, if value was 0.00000009 or 9e-8, the method will call on printScientificNotation(value * 10, powerOfTen - 1); eight times and System.out.println(value + " x 10^" + powerOfTen); once.

So the it is called recursively by the exponent for e. But how do I represent this by big O notation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a trick question? That code will recurse infinitely for some of its inputs (for example, value=-1.0, powerOfTen=0), therefore its runtime is not O(f(n)) for any finite function f(n).

**Edit**: Assuming `value > 0.0`...

The run time (or recursion depth, if you prefer to look at it that way) does not depend on the value of `powerOfTen`, only on `value`.  For an intial input `value` in the range [1.0, 10.0), the run time is constant, so O(1),  For `value` in [10.0, +infinity), you divide `value` by 10 for each recursive call until `value < 10.0`, so the runtime is  O(log<sub>10</sub>(`value`)).  A similar argument can be made for `value` in the range (0.0,1.0), but note that log<sub>10</sub> `value` is negative for this case.  So your final answer might involve an absolute value operation.  Then you might consider whether it's necessary to specify the logarithm base in the context of an asymptotic complexity analysis.  Hopefully you can take it from there!

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add to assume that inputs will not cause any infinite loops